# Easing with a range slider and back again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got a range slider which I'm using to control a value in an input box. The values we're using can be quite high on the max end so we wanted finer control for smaller numbers before spanning out quicker for larger numbers.

To try and tackle this issue I used an easing equation and instead of time based it on the slider value. This works great for setting the text in the input field. The problem I'm having is now going back the other way. I want to let a user type into the input field and for the slider to move to where it should be based on the easing equation. For this I need to some how work backwards but I don't really have any idea how to convert the function around.

I [have a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvGKPz) of what I have so far, any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var min_amount = 10;
  var max_amount = 2000;
  var ease = function(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d;
    return c*t*t + b;
  }

  $scope.transaction = {
    slider: 0,
    amount: 1
  }

 $scope.sliderUpdate = function() {
  var  quint = ease($scope.transaction.slider, min_amount, max_amount - min_amount, 100); console.log(quint);
   $scope.transaction.amount = quint;
 }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below function for that.

```
  var reverseEase = function(x, b, c, d) {
    return d * Math.sqrt((x - b)/ c);
  }
```

here `x` is the ease value.

Working snippet.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var min_amount = 10;
  var max_amount = 2000;
  var ease = function(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d;
    return c * t * t + b;
  }

  var reverseEase = function(x, b, c, d) {
    return d * Math.sqrt((x - b) / c)
  }

  $scope.transaction = {
    slider: 0,
    amount: 1
  }

  $scope.transaction.reverseamount = 0;
  $scope.sliderUpdate = function() {
    var quint = ease($scope.transaction.slider, min_amount, max_amount - min_amount, 100);
    console.log(quint);
    $scope.transaction.amount = quint;

    $scope.transaction.reverseamount = reverseEase(quint, min_amount, max_amount - min_amount, 100);
  }

  $scope.transaction.reverseamount2 = reverseEase(10, min_amount, max_amount - min_amount, 100);
  $scope.transaction.valueChange = function(val) {
    if (!isNaN(val) && val > 9 && val < 2001) {
      $scope.transaction.reverseamount2 = reverseEase(val, min_amount, max_amount - min_amount, 100);
      $scope.errormsg = "";
    } else {
      $scope.errormsg = "invalid value";
    }
  }

  $scope.sliderUpdate2 = function(value) {
    $scope.transaction.inputValue = ease(value, min_amount, max_amount - min_amount, 100);
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
.errorColor {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic Pull to Refresh</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>

    <input type="text" value="1" ng-model="transaction.amount" />

    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" id="input-topUp-range" ng-model="transaction.slider" ng-change="sliderUpdate();" />

    <br/>{{transaction.reverseamount}}
    <br/>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" id="input-topUp-range2" ng-model="transaction.reverseamount" />

    <hr/>Number(between 10 to 2000):
    <input ng-model="transaction.inputValue" ng-keyup="transaction.valueChange(transaction.inputValue)" />
    <br/>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" id="input-topUp-range3" ng-model="transaction.reverseamount2" ng-change="sliderUpdate2(transaction.reverseamount2);" />
    <span class="errorColor">{{errormsg}}</span>
  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```